# How to deserialize in JSON.NET a list of objects with a nested list of objects?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have json file like this.

```
[
  {
    "listMember": [
      {
        "Name": "Cris",
        "Position": "Командир",
        "Age": 50,
        "Experience": 25
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sandra",
        "Position": "Стюардесса",
        "Age": 25,
        "Experience": 5
      }
    ],
    "Id": 31004,
    "Type": "грузовой",
    "Model": "Bell",
    "Year_of_issue": 2007,
    "Seats": 150,
    "Carrying": 50,
    "Maintenance": "12.04.2017"
  }
]
```

List of airplane:

```
class Airplane
    {
        public List<Member> listMember = new List<Member>();
        public Int16 Id { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public String Model { get; set; }
        public Int16 Year_of_issue { get; set; }
        public Int16 Seats { get; set; }
        public Int16 Carrying { get; set; }
        public String Maintenance { get; set; }
}
```

Nested List of members.

```
class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public UInt16 Age { get; set; }
    public UInt16 Experience { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to deserialize this file.
I tried to do so...

```
List<Airport> airport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Airport>>(json);
```

But it is not working.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'lab7.Airport' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your Deserialization attempt doesn't match up, your class name is `Airplane` but you try to deserialize to `List<Airport>`

Comment: Your code works fine (if you change Airport to Airplane), perhaps something goes wrong with loading of json.

Comment: Is Airport array of Airplanes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your classes with this website: [JSON to C#](http://json2csharp.com/)

It results in this code:

```
public class ListMember
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ListMember> listMember { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year_of_issue { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }
    public int Carrying { get; set; }
    public string Maintenance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: He already has his JSON objects.